# In languages that don't allow underscores in integer constants, is it a good practice to create a constant for 1 billion?

Tags: coding-style

In languages that don't allow [underscores in integer literals](http://blog.quov.is/2011/11/29/did-you-know-1-underscores-in-ruby-numbers/), is it a good idea to create a constant for 1 billion?  e.g. in C++:

```
size_t ONE_BILLION = 1000000000;
```

Certainly, we shouldn't create constants for small numbers like 100.  But with 9 zeros, it's arguably easy to leave off a zero or add an extra one in code like this:

```
tv_sec = timeInNanosec / 1000000000;
tv_nsec = timeInNanosec % 1000000000;
```

Comment: I hope everyone here votes for **NO**. That way, maybe one day my bank will transfer one billion dollars to my account because a programmer didn't use a constant and misplaced a zero! :)

Comment: Why not create constants for small numbers? What does 100 mean? Unless there is some context, it's a magic number.

Comment: How long will it take you to figure out what's going on when a disgruntled dev changes the value of ONE_BILLION to 1000000000.01? Hello Office Space.

Comment: @MrFox *ssshhhhhhhhh* .... I'm hacking the banks source code to make that change.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini In general, mistakes can go either way.  But when it comes to your bank, mistakes will always go against you.

Comment: Consider writing `1e9`, `10^9` or `1_000_000_000` if the language you are using supports it.

Comment: I like JohnB's proposed answer, but I think it better to leave it as ONE_BILLION with a comment as "//nanaseconds per second", otherwise it looks like your comment is frivolous and came from an idiot.

Comment: you might also add a `L` suffix so it become a long and you don't get bitten by integer overflow

Comment: I've had various people tell me that it's PROBABLY best to use no numbers in your code whatsoever (possibly excepting 1 and 0 which make nice loop terminations).  I don't know if they really believed it, but it might be an interesting experiment.

Comment: @MrFox: Considering that `size_t` is not going to accept double literals, not very long.

Comment: [Long scale or short scale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_and_short_scales) billion?

Comment: How about 'tv_nsec = timeInNanosec - tv_sec'?

Comment: As another comment, size_t is supposed to be a variable able to contain the size of an item in bytes. Which is certainly not the case here so this should not be a size_t

Comment: I'm trying to think of a language that does allow _ in integer constants.  Can anyone name some of those?

Comment: C, C++, Python, Java before 7.  So, most of the popular languages.

Comment: @Mark0978: Ada, Perl.

Comment: @MartinC.Martin: Those are languages that *don't* allow _ in integer constants.

Comment: @ratchetfreak: In C and C++, the `L` suffix is unnecessary; an integer constant is automatically of a type big enough to hold it. On the other hand, an expression like `1000 * 1000 * 1000` *can* overflow, since `1000` is of type `int`.

Comment: @mark newest java, D

Comment: @MartinC.Martin While C++ does allow for underscores in numeric literals you can split up large (or complex literals) using the token pasting operator`##`, ie: `#define ONE_BILLION 1 ## 000 ## 000 ## 000`. Less readable than underscores, but it does arguably simplify visual verification.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Most languages feature some kind of exponential notation. A million is `1e6`, (meaning 1 times 10 to the power of 6). This basically solves the issue even better than most propositions here.

In a lot of C-like languages, the **scientific notation** is however defining a **floating point type**, which is unfortunate if you really need an int. However, you can easily type-cast that constant to avoid implicit conversions in your formular.

`n / int(1e9)` would divide by a billion.

In your example, dealing with physical quantities (time in nanosecond), I would generally ask myself whether integer is the right type. In fact a floating point `double` might be better suited when dealing with measurable quantities (although there are of course cases where you would prefer a `long long`).

Comment: I think the NANOSECONDS_IN_ONE_SECOND solution is much clearer and neater

Comment: The Question was about integer liberals and I propose to use scientific notation. Whether to do this in place or by defining a constant is an issue of structuring code that was not asked for in the question. Defining a constant adds limited abstraction, I would write a conversion function/macro to achieve better abstraction

Comment: would casting a very large double to an int not risk the typical rounding difference problems of floating point numbers?

Comment: with normal precision integer types this shouldnot be a problem as long as you use a double precision float to convert from. you are right when using values of the `long long` range.

Answer (score 146):

Create one called NANOSECONDS_IN_ONE_SECOND instead as that what it represents.

Or a shorter, better name if you can think of one.

Comment: I'd say `Nanoseconds_Per_Second` but this is, in my opinion, the correct answer.

Comment: @Mathew I don't get your point. There's nothing wrong with saying millimeters per meter. You may be implying that it is redundant, in that nanosecond MEANS one billion fractions of a second, but there's nothing wrong in stating it again. It's like saying 1 + 1 = 2. "x per y" continues to make more sense when x and y are disjoint, like "units per half dozen" or "nanoseconds per millisecond"

Comment: @MathewFoscarini Actually, no, in this context it's not.  If it were, a constant named `NANOSECONDS` is meaningless as you can't tell what it's supposed to apply to.  Likewise, `NANOSECONDS_PER_MICROSECOND` is a similar valid constant that makes sense.

Comment: How can you have `NANOSECONDS_PER_MICROSECOND`? That's like saying `KILOMETERS PER MILE`. I must not be understanding the term correctly.

Comment: oh! I get it. Sorry. `KILOMETERS_PER_MILE = 1.60934`

Comment: I think what Mathew was trying to say is that traditionally we use per to describe units of one type in units of another type, such as miles per hour. The confusions was why we would use per to describe units of one type in units of the same type. Subtle difference in the meaning of per is all.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini, "millimeters per meter" is a way to remove the unit on the conversion to get the raw value. `1mm/1m = 1000`, which is *exactly* the point of what's being done here.

Comment: I like `x_PER_y` as it is analogous to x/y and makes dimensional analysis easier. For example, when you see something like `NANOSEC_PER_DAY = NANOSEC_PER_SEC * SEC_PER_MIN * MIN_PER_HOUR * HOURS_PER_DAY`, it is easy to verify that the units on "top" and "bottom" cancel one another out.

Comment: Why so much typing? `NS_PER_SEC` should be obvious to anyone who ought to be dealing with nanoseconds.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree, his answer is better as it explains why. Vote for his, not mine,

Comment: @FumbleFingers Why would you downvote this answer? Do you find it's wrong? I think it's prefectly valid as it hits the point in that **you should name constants as per their meaning, not just for their value**. I, for once, upvoted both (upvotes are free, you know).

Comment: @Nadir: I was visited by the insidious [Jack Daniel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_Daniel's) last night. I apologise to JohnB for the gratuitously inflammatory comment, which I've deleted. But I still prefer the other answer.

Comment: @RexKerr: Fine here, but that pattern would cause a conflict for µs and ms: both are MS_PER_SEC when capitalised. Personally I might just use constants like NANO, MICRO, MILLI because whether you're talking about seconds or meters or teslas isn't relevant.

Comment: @Joren, my experience has been the people tend to use `US` to indicate microseconds, for the purposes of constants. It's unambiguous when used in a context where the constant represents some sort of measurement.

Comment: @Joren - Using anything other than unicode Mu or Latin u/U for micro is asking for confusion.  Also, is `NANO` 1e9 or 1e-9?  Can't really tell...so you can't just do that.

Comment: @RexKerr If you use `NANO` for anything other than 1e-9, you likely have other problems as well... now, `NANOSECONDS_PER_SECOND` would definitely be 1e9.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - I agree, but Joren was proposing to use it for 1e9 (to mean `NS_PER_SEC`).  And if he is proposing that for `NANO` I can't trust what `NANO` means as a constant.

Comment: @RexKerr: "Using anything other than unicode Mu or Latin u/U for micro is asking for confusion." - Yes that's exactly my point?

Comment: @RexKerr: I most certainly wasn't proposing to define NANO = 1e9. Obviously a nano-anything is 1e-9.

Comment: Is it?  There are no basis units smaller ?  (Hint: Plank's time) There is no indication of point of view or context with nano by itself.  Coupled with a _PER_SECOND or _PER_MICROSECOND or any other basis the purpose of the coefficient becomes clear.  Without it, confusion or assumption.  Some assumptions are safer than others, but still..

Comment: @RexKerr `NS_PER_SEC` is not even consistent with itself. `NS_PER_S` maybe? More time is spent reading code than writing it. I feel that you should code for ease of reading, not typing. Most IDE's will lend themselves to making `NANOSECONDS_PER_SECOND` only a few keystrokes anyway.

Comment: Watch out for `#define NANOSECONDS_PER_SECOND 100000000`. (Hint: count the zeros.)

Answer (score 68):

Constants are meant to give numbers meaning. There is not any additional meaning in `ONE_BILLION` to `1000000000`. Actually, it makes it more confusing, because in different natural languages, a billion means something different (either a thousand million or a million million)! If you want to write it shorter, there's a good chance your programming language allows the use scientific notation, i.e. `1e9`. Otherwise, I agree with @JohnB, that this number really means the number of nanoseconds in a second, so name it that.

Comment: Good pointing that billion in different languages mean different amount of zeros.

Comment: would suggest changing regular languages to natural languages. regular means something else...

Comment: Different interpretations of "billion" in languages such a good point! Why can't I upvote your answer twice!

Comment: You don't need different languages. You don't even need different countries. In British English, "billion" means something different before and after 1974 in official communications (mass media and government), and *both* usages still exist.

Comment: "*There is not any additional meaning in ONE_BILLION to 10000000000.*. I disagree. (Hint: I deliberately misquoted you and added another zero; would have have noticed if I hadn't mentioned it?)

Answer (score 27):

For one or two usages, I would use the convention:

```
tv_sec = timeInNanosec / (1000 * 1000 * 1000);
tv_nsec = timeInNanosec % (1000 * 1000 * 1000);
```

It's perfectly self explanatory, gets compiled to a constant and it's hard to screw up.

Also, it's very useful in cases such as:

```
var Time = 24 * 60 * 60;
```

where it's easy to see we are talking about one day in seconds.

Comment: This is what I usually do. It also has the advantage that I won't forget that I defined NANOSECONDS_IN_ONE_SECOND yesterday and define NANOSECONDS_PER_SECOND today. And perhaps ONE_AMERICAN_BILLION tomorrow.

Comment: Surely 'SecondsInOneDay = 24 * 60 * 60' is easier still?

Comment: @JBRWilkinson sure, my initial snippet was using a class `instance.Time = ...`, but then I dumbed it down...

Comment: In C or C++, `(1000 * 1000 * 1000)` is of type `int`, which is only required to be 16 bits, so it can overflow. You can write `(1000L * 1000L * 1000L)` to avoid that.

Comment: I do this a lot. It works very well.

Answer (score 10):

The length of the value is not what defines whether a constant is needed or not.

You use constants to avoid [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29), not to avoid typing.

For example these are perfectly valid constants:

```
public static final int CLOSE_CURSORS_AT_COMMIT = 1;
public static final int CONCUR_READ_ONLY = 2;
public static final int CONCUR_UPDATABLE = 3;
public static final int FETCH_FORWARD = 4;
public static final int FETCH_REVERSE = 5; 
public static final int FETCH_UNKNOWN = 6;
public static final int HOLD_CURSORS_OVER_COMMIT = 7;
public static final int TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY = 8;
public static final int TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE = 9;
public static final int TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE = 10;
```

Use:

```
public static final int NANOSECS_PER_SECOND = 1000000000;
```

(code samples are in Java, translate to your favorite language )

Comment: +1 Named numbers are nearly useless.  The purpose of constants it to give meaning to those numbers.  What do they represent?  What thing are they counting or limiting or formally named coefficient? Not what is the value of the count.

Comment: Seeing as we're talking Java, I'll make the observation that, [as of Java 7, we can put underscores in numbers to help readability!](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/underscores-literals.html)

Comment: Those are terrible examples of valid constants. They should have been enums, except they were created before enums.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström They were indeed created before enums, they are part of the ResultSet class, in the SQL package of the Java SDK.

Comment: @user61852: Yes, that was my point. So they are terrible examples of valid constants. Their integer values are entirely unmeaningful.

Comment: @ChristofferHammarström They're bad because now we have enums but not for being unmeaningful. Enum didn't exist when these classes were created and in order to differentiate between mutually exclusive options like FETCH_FORWARD and FETCH_REVERSE is giving them a different value. The value doesn't matter, just the fact that they are different.

Comment: @JustinC: Should have been "+ONE Named numbers are nearly useless" ;)

Answer (score 8):

An American or European billion?

(or in technical terms, a billion in the short scale or long scale - one is 1000 million, the other is a million million).

Given this confusion, then I'd say yes - it makes sense to define it once and keep with it, likewise applies to any constant you need to agree the definition on - define it once.

Comment: "An American or European billion?" - "What? I don't know that! Ahhhhh!!!!"

Comment: In the UK, at least, we've long since adopted the 1e9 billion.

Comment: @Tesserex - well, you have to know these things when you're a king, you know.

Answer (score 5):

#### Reasons Not To

Firstly, here is a reason not write any underscores or use any trick to simulate it: it makes the constants harder to find in the code. Suppose that some program exhibits, somewhere in its operation, hard-coded value 1500000 for some parameter.  I want to know where in the source code of the program this actually occurs, so I grep the code for `1500000`, and find nothing. Why? Might it be in hexadecimal (but why for such a round decimal number). Unbeknownst to me, the constant is actually written as `1_500_000`. I needed the regex `1_?500_?000`.

#### Guiding Characters in Comment

Just because one kind of visual aid is not available, or we don't wish to use it for the above reason, doesn't mean that we cannot take advantage of the two dimensions of the text file to create an alternative visual aid:

```
foo = bar / 1000000000;
//           --^--^--^
```

With this we can easily convince ourselves that there are three groups of three zeros. Yet, we can still grep the source code for `1000000000` and find it.

#### Syntax Coloring

A text editor with programmable syntax coloring can be made to color groups digits in numeric constants with alternating colors for better readability. We don't have to do anything in the code.

#### Preprocessing: C, C++, Objective C

Now, if we really want some commas between digits, in C and C++ we can use some preprocessing:

```
/* Four digit base TH-ousand constant macro */
/* Condensed using Horner's rule */
#define TH(A,B,C,D) ((((((A) * 1000) + (B)) * 1000) + (C)) * 1000 + D)

tv_sec = nanoseconds / TH(1,000,000,000)
```

Works for numbers like `TH(1,234,567,890)`.

A macro similar to TH can also work with token pasting rather than arithmetic. In the C preprocessor, the binary `##` operator ("token paste") can be used in a macro body in order to paste together two operands into a single token. One or both of the operands can be macro arguments.  The downside here (creating a risk for us) is that if the resulting catenation isn't a valid token, the behavior is undefined.

```
#define TOK4(A, B, C, D) A ## B ## C ## D
```

Now

```
TOK4(1,000,000,000)       /* produces the single token 1000000000 */
TOK4(1,123,000,000.0E+2)  /* produces the single token 1123000000.0E+2 */
TOK4(pr,in,t,f)           /* produces the token printf */
TOK4(#,*,a,b)             /* undefined behavior, #*ab is not valid token syntax */
```

C programs that paste together identifiers and use the results to name global variables and functions exist and are awful to work with because they are impervious to tools like GNU id-utils and ctags.

Comment: +1 for one of the best abuses of the preprocessor I've seen. I'd still go with NSEC_PER_SEC or something in production, though.

Comment: Very nearly -1 for abusing the preprocessor :)

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, that sounds like a reasonable idea.  Off-by-one DIGIT errors are even worse than the infamous off-by-one errors.  Although, it may create confusion for other people (including your future self) to read the code.

A more explanatory name like NANOSEC_PER_SEC seems good, as it would add clarity where it is used for time.  However, it makes no sense to use in contexts other than time, and it would be impractical to create a separate 1,000,000,000 for every situation.

What you really want to do, silly as it seems at first, is 'divide over sec'.  This leaves NANO_PER, which is not only language-independent (10^9 in America and Europe) but also situation-independent (no limiting on the units), and it is easy to type and read.

Comment: this post is rather hard to read (wall of text). Would you mind [edit]ing it into a better shape?

Answer (score 3):

In general it's a bad idea to use scalar constants for unit conversions, and if you find yourself making constants for such things you're doing conversion in way too many places.

When you have a quantity of one unit (say, 10 seconds), and want to convert to another unit (i.e. nanoseconds); this is precisely the time to use the type system of your language to ensure that the units are actually scaled as you intend.

Make your function take a `Nanoseconds` parameter, and provide conversion operators and/or constructors in that class for `Seconds`, `Minutes`, or what-have-you.  This is where your `const int` or `#define` or `1e9` seen in other answers belongs.

This avoids having variables of ambiguous units floating around your code; and prevents entire swathes of bugs from where the wrong multiply/divide was applied, or was already applied, or the quantity was actually distance instead of time, or...

Also, in such classes it's good to make construction from plain scalarsprivate and use a static "MakeSeconds(int)" or similar to discourage sloppy use of opaque numbers.

More specifically to your example, in C++ check out [Boost.Chrono](http://www.boost.org/libs/chrono).

Comment: + At the very least, use a common type with a scaling or offset factor from a basis, much like the often maligned timezone.

Answer (score 1):

I personally wouldn't consider it good practice to create a constant unless it needs to be a constant. If its going to be in multiple places and having it defined at the top of the file for modification / or testing is going to be useful then absolutely.

If its just because its awkward to type ? then no.

Personally if I got someone else's code that had a constant defined, I generally consider this to be an important aspect of the code. E.g. tcp keep alive timers, maximum number of connections allowed. If I had to debug it I would probably pay a lot of unneeded attention to it trying to figure out why / where its being used.

Comment: I get the joke but if bank programers had to make a constant for every number you could transfer the software would be gigantic, unmanageable and slow. I could only imagine what that would be like, imagine being told it would take 3 working days to transfer money to .... OH MY GOD, THATS IT!!!

Comment: My bank does take 3 days to transfer money :(

Comment: @MathewFoscarini bankers use Excel they do not need programmers ;)

Comment: @Simon Depending on language and compiler, constants should be optimized into the code, incurring little overhead. I understand your point, but constants can be used wherever using a name instead of a magic number would help code readability.

Comment: Awkward to read is much more of an issue than awkward to type.

Answer (score 0):

When you think about why you wrote "1 Billion" instead of "1000000000" in your question title, you'll realise why the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

```
const int Million = 1000 * 1000;
const int Billion = 1000 * Million;
```

or

`const int SciMega = 1000 * 1000;
const int SciGiga = 1000 * SciMega;`

Regarding number of nanoseconds per second: nano is the "inverse" of giga.

```
Kilo  Mega  Giga   etc.
10^3  10^6  10^9
Milli Micro Nano   etc.
10^-3 10^-6 10^-9
```

<strike>Note the "Sci" - for scientific, as in computers, the meanings of kilo, mega, giga etc. are different: 1024 (2^10), 1024*1024 (2^20), etc. 
2 megabytes is not 2,000,000 bytes.</strike>

**UPDATE** Commenter pointed out that special terms exist for digital exponents of 2: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte

Comment: *"2 megabytes is not 2,000,000 bytes."* Ask any spinning-platter hard disk manufacturer you want. (Not the downvoter, btw.)

Comment: @michaelkjorling this is a programming question, not a business ethics or marketing one. I do agree about hard drives, but that's a different topic. And ouch about the down votes!

Comment: Actually, 2 Megabytes is 2,000,000 bytes. 2 Mebibytes is 2,097,152 bytes. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte

Comment: @vy32 thanks, never heard of that before. Will update my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Mr.TA, no problem! We're working hard to bring Computer Science into compliance with SI Units! Join the club.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create a constant for your big literals. You would need a constant for each such literal, which is (in my opinion) a complete joke. If you desperately need to make your literals clearer without the help of things like syntax highlighting, you could (though I would not) create functions or macros to make your life "easier":

```
#define SPLIT3(x, y, z) x##y##z

int largeNumber1 = SPLIT3(123,456,789);
int largeNumber2 = 123456789;
```